# I tried to fetch single document data from firestore before the view data display "Null check operator used on a null value" in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch single document data from firestore before the view data display the "Null check operator used on a null value"  error and after show document data perfectly. I canot understand what is the error on my code. I used null safety in my code but..

**error screen shot**

[image]

model class code

```
class Articles {
  final  String id;
  final  String topic;
  final  String description;
  final  String url;
  final DateTime? birthday;



  Articles({
    required  this.id,
    required this.topic,
    required  this.description,
    required   this.url,
    required  this.birthday,
  });

  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(
      id: json['id'] ?? '',
    topic: json['topic']  ?? '',
    url: json['url'] ?? '',
    description: json['description'] ?? '',
      birthday: json['birthday'] != null
          ? (json['birthday'] as Timestamp).toDate()
          : null
     );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'topic': topic,
      'url': url,
      'description': description,
      'birthday': birthday?.millisecondsSinceEpoch


};
  }
```

**view one code**

```
  Future<void> getArticle() async {
    final id = widget.id;
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/${user?.uid}/articles/$id');
    final snapshot = reference.get();

    final result = await snapshot.then(
        (snap) => snap.data() == null ? null : Articles.fromJson(snap.data()!));
    setState(() {
      oneArticle = result;
      loading = false;
    });
  }
```

UI code

```
oneArticle!.topic,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    decorationColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 1,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  oneArticle!.url,
                  height: 350,
                  width: width * 0.8,
                ),
```

how to fix this error?
console
[image]

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: The null check operator does not ensure that you will never see this error. The data you are getting from firestore may contain `null` value and as seen in the model class, you added the required parameter in each object. Adding the `required` keyword in a constructor indicates that the expected value should not be `null`.

Comment: sure @NirjanMunshi I 'll

Comment: I added console error

Comment: the problem is on the `view_articles.dart` file. line number `160:67`. If that line contains the code you have added in the UI Code snippet, then in `oneArticle!.topic`, `oneArticle!` is getting `null` value.

Comment: okay... how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this...
I added loading before fetch data

```
body: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage(Config.app_background), fit: BoxFit.fill),
  ),
  child: loading // <--- added this 
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) // <--- added this 
      : Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // ...
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
),
```

Comment: Yes, this can be a way to solve this problem. What I understand is, the value is coming the after the UI is created. Thus throwing the null exception. 

You can handle this by using `StreamBuilder` or `Observable` or you can update the state by calling `setState()` after you receive the value from firestore.

Comment: yeah that's right